# How can I delete a worksheet calling the code from MS Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

When the code below reaches the .Delete instruction it goes into an endless loop. When stopped in the Task Manager an error message "Automation error" is displayed. When the Debug button in the error message is pressed the .Delete line is highlighted. The sheet isn't deleted. The alert message isn't displayed.

```
Sub DeleteXlTable(Wb As Workbook, _
                  Frm As fTextLib)
    ' SSY 047 ++ 30 Dec 2018

    Dim LibWs As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Excel.Range

'    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set LibWs = SetLibWs(Wb, Frm)
    With LibWs
        If .ListObjects.Count = 1 Then
            If Wb.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
                With .UsedRange
                    .Columns.Delete
                    .Rows.RowHeight = 12.75
                End With
                .Name = "Sheet1"
            Else
                .Delete
            End If
        Else
            Set Rng = .ListObjects(Frm.CbxTbl.Text).Range
            Do While Rng.Row > NwsFirstLibRow
                If Not .Cells(Rng.Row - 1, NwsKey).ListObject Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Set Rng = Rng.Offset(-1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count + 1)
            Loop
            Rng.Rows.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The code is called in a VBA project embedded in MS Word. The Excel application is called properly and available. The Worksheet exists and is accessible at the time of the error. I tried replacing the line with the full object's name, Wb.Worksheets(LibWs.Name).Delete, with the same result. I tried deleting the ListObject before deleting the sheet. The table was deleted but the same error occurred on the next line.
Similar code run from a stand-alone Excel application works perfectly, even if the deleted sheet is the active one. I wonder whether I should save the workbook before deleting the sheet but don't know why that should make a difference. Any ideas what I might do?

Comment: It might be because you aren't turning off the DisplayAlerts in Excel, you're doing that in Word only. Excel is probably bubbling up the "Are you sure you want to delete this sheet" pop-up message. It is waiting for input from you. Try, `Wb.Parent.DisplayAlerts = False`  where you have `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` commented out, see if that does it.

Comment: Good point! But the Alerts=False line is already commented out, and code execution doesn't reach to alerts. However, I should have mentioned that the Window isn't active or visible when the error occurs.

Comment: Far too pessimistic! I was. Your bubble idea seems to hit the nail on the head. The error disappeared after I corrected the object and disabled the alert display. Please put your solution in an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks a million! I was planning on caving in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our earlier conversation, it seems as if the alert in Excel in causing an issue.

Add:

`Wb.Parent.DisplayAlerts = False`

Where:

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

was commented out.